# What is the domain of $f(x) = x$?

Tags: functions, notation, terminology, definition

I understand that the domain is typically defined as the set of objects for which a function is defined. So, given a function $f(x) = x$, how can I figure out its domain? Is $bananas$ part of the domain, given that the function seems to defined for $bananas$ in that $f(bananas) = bananas$? Indeed, is the domain simply **everything** for this function?

**EDIT**

I am told that I should specify the domain and codomain as part of the definition of a function, and use something like $f: A \to B : x \mapsto f(x)$.  So is $A$ here the domain and $B$ the codomain?

Also, can I say $f : \mathbb{R}\setminus{\{0,1\}} \to \mathbb{R} : x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: A function comes equipped with a domain, so if $bananas$ is an element of that domain, then sure.

Comment: If you only know the formula $f(x) = x$, then you do not have the full definition of the function, which must also include the domain and codomain. So without further context, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Nitpicking: $f(x)=x$ isn't even a function, it's an equality. If you get rid of the notational abuse, does the question remain?

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645039/codomains-and-the-definition-of-a-function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a person is to talk about a function "legally" then he should specify the domain, the codomain, and the corresponding rule of the function. From example, it is sloppy to write "the function $f(x) = x^{2}$" (though of course it would be okay if the context is clear enough); ideally the author might try to say instead "the function $f(x) = x^{2}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$" or "the function $f: x \mapsto x^{2}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$". What we are given is merely the corresponding rule "$f(x) = x$" of a mysterious function $f$, so there is nothing much to say from there on.

Comment: I've never seen the notation “$f : x \mapsto x^2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$” before.  Maybe “$f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, $x\mapsto x^2$” is more conventional.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, Yeah I think so :). You know sometimes for convenience I did that. At least I think it won't harm, for the transpose of the order does not cost any information loss.

Comment: @Bram28, Oh that would be a problem because $1/0$ is meaningless :). So at most $f: x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{ 0 \} \to \mathbb{R}$. We have to get rid of $0$ in order we be consistent.

Comment: @EricClapton  Thanks! ... and sorry for deleting that comment .. I thought it was better as an edit to my post.

Comment: @EricClapton So would you say that the domain is part of the *definition* of a function?

Comment: @Bram28, Yes it is (but it is not just because I think so :)). If you check any introductory analysis textbook, then you can find usually in the very beginning the author tries to define what it means for an object to be a function. For example, you might want to check Terry Tao's Analysis textbooks. In book one I think, he defines from the aspect of logic what it means by a function.

Comment: @EricClapton So when I get one of those more complicated functions with lots of square roots and who knows what, and I am asked to 'figure out the domain', then I should just be able to say 'well, just look at the very definition of this very function'?

Comment: @Bram28, Specifically, questions such as "what is the domain of the function $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$" expect you to answer the largest possible reasonable set as the domain. Here the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} | x \geq 0 \}$ is an appropriate answer. Because no number $x < 0$ is such that $\sqrt{x}$ is meaningful. But for a practical purpose certainly you can let $f: x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$ merely, say.