# A well defined or unambiguous function

Tags: real-analysis, definition

I was looking through my lecture notes, and I noticed the definition of a function:

One of the three components of a function, $f :X \to Y$ is as follows: '$f$ is a $\mathbf{well-defined}$ rule that assigns a unique elements $f(x) \in Y$ to each $x \in X.$'

It then goes on to say:
'$f$ is a $\mathbf{well-defined}$ or $\mathbf{unambiguous}$ if and only if, $f(x)=f(x')$ whenever $x=x'.$'

Surely this is incorrect, as this means that the definition does not include the constant function?

As if $f : X \to Y$ and $f(x)=a$, then for $x, x' \in X $ and $x \neq x'$, $f(x) =f(x')$?

Comment: 1. This definition is terrible. 2. Assuming the definition was actually good, what you claim would be incorrect. You would have to argue that $x=x'$ and $f(x)\neq f(x')$, for some $x,x'$ in $X$.  See for instance [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185073/what-is-the-domain-of-fx-x), [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645039/codomains-and-the-definition-of-a-function) and other similar and related question here on MSE for greater insight.

Comment: @GitGud the full definition is ' A function $f$ from $X$ to $Y$ consists of 3 things: 1. A set $X=Dom(f)$; 2. A set $Y=codom(f)$ and a $\mathbf{well-defined}$ rule that assigns a unique elements $f(x) \in Y$ to each $x \in X.$' is this still terrible?

Comment: The definition says WHENEVER x = x' then f(x) = f(x') not x= x' iff f(x) = f(x').  If f(x) = c is then constant function.  Then:  WHENEVER x = x' then f(x) = f(x') = c.  The definition holds.  When if FAILS is if you have a non-function so that f(x) sometimes c or sometimes equals d or sometimes both all for the same x.

Comment: @Gurjinder Not terrible anymore $\ddot \smile$. The problem with what you typed on the question's body is that writing stuff such as $f(x)$ is only meaningful **after** you define the concept of "*function* $f$". You can't write $f(x)$ before knowing that $f$ is a function. **Edit:** I would still prefer to write "unique element $y$ in $Y$, which is denoted by $f(x)$".

Comment: It's a more confusing then nesc. definition, but it is a correct definition.  The problem with trying to find a precise definition of something that is poorly defined is that the thing being defined is wrong.  It's practically impossible to describe an example when $f(x) \ne f(x)$ which is what the are saying.  If $x = x'$ and $f(x) \ne f(x)$ (sometimes) then $f$ is not well defined.

Comment: @fleablood ahh, i understand.

Comment: @GitGud ohh, understood.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a constant function is not a counterexample to the definition. If $P$ implies $Q$, then the negation of $P$ does not necessarily imply the negation of $Q$. It is that the negation of $Q$ implies that of $P$. Think of this example: Suppose we agree that if $x$ is a person then $x$ will die. From this it does not follow that if $x$ is not a person then $x$ will not die. But it follows from the implication that if $x$ will not die then $x$ is not a person.

According to the definition that confused you, it is trivial for a constant function to satisfy the condition required; the functional value of a constant function at every point of its domain is the same single point of its codomain.