# Does the set theoretic definition of a function include the information for what the codomain is?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

I think I remember reading that a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a subset of $A\times B$ such that for each $a\in A$ there is exactly one element of $f$ such that $\{a\}\in F$ (assuming $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, although I guess this detail isn't important probably).

Wouldn't this definition mean that we cannot know what the codomain of the function is?

Comment: With that definition, two functions are equal if and only if they have the same domain and the same correspondence rule. A better definition would be the following: given sets $A$ and $B$, a function from $A$ to $B$ is a pair $(f,B)$, where $f \subseteq A \times B$ has the property: for any $a \in A$ there is a unique $b \in B$ such that $(a,b) \in f$.

Comment: have you seen that definition somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I believe that in any serious set theory book there is something very similar. Oh, you're right, let me fix that.

Comment: Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645039/codomains-and-the-definition-of-a-function) discusion.

Comment: Thank you, I think it is appropriate that I close this as duplicate of that